# how to import [spacy] .pos_ on python

Tags: python, spacy

i try to do a code to get a parser on some words by using spacy and its methods like .pos_ and .dep_ but i have an error that i dont understand
what can i do ?

```
import spacy, textphonographer
test = spacy.load('fr_core_news_md')

def fct(tok1, tok2):
    token1 = test(tok1)
    token2 = test(tok2)

    if token1.pos_ == "DET":
        if token2.pos_ == "NOUN" or token2.pos_ == "ADJ":
            print(token1.pos_,"_", token2.pos_)
            return True

print (fct("suis", "une"))
_________________________________
File "doc.py", line 37, in fct
if token1.pos_ == "DET":

AttributeError: 'spacy.tokens.doc.Doc' object has no attribute 'pos_'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace token.pos_ with token[0].pos_

```
if token1[0].pos_ == "DET":
    if token2[0].pos_ == "NOUN" or token2[0].pos_ == "ADJ":
        print(token1[0].pos_,"_", token2[0].pos_)
        return True
```